# ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MARTE71.EXPENSE_PROJECT_FK) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello everyone and thank you for taking the time to help.
I have been making a sql script which works fine as far as i am aware except for one table called expense, i have been trying to fix it for 3 days and i am still getting an error,
 ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MARTE71.EXPENSE_PROJECT_FK) violated - parent key not found.

I assume i have made a mistake with the foreign key in expense, however i have tried all i know and still it fails may you please have a look at my logic and if possible the cause to the error and possible solution.

I really appreciate any help and advice.
I shall attach my create and populate script below.

Many thanks again.

```
    CREATE TABLE project
    (
        project_no          NUMBER(4),
        project_code        VARCHAR2(8),
        description         VARCHAR2(50),  
        client_no           NUMBER(4),    
        mgr_no              NUMBER(4),

    CONSTRAINT project_pk           PRIMARY KEY (project_no),
    CONSTRAINT project_employee_fk  FOREIGN KEY (mgr_no) 
                        REFERENCES employee(employee_no)
    );


    -- planned duration is expressed as a number of weeks
    -- fees-basis can take only the following values VS, VN, CS, CN, FQ

    CREATE TABLE stage
    (
        stage_id            NUMBER(4),
        project_no          NUMBER(4),
        stage_no            NUMBER(4),
        description         VARCHAR2(50),
        start_date          DATE,
        planned_duration    NUMBER(4,1),               
        fees_basis          VARCHAR2(2),
        estimate_date       DATE,

    CONSTRAINT stage_pk         PRIMARY KEY (stage_id),
    CONSTRAINT stage_project_fk FOREIGN KEY (project_no) 
                        REFERENCES project (project_no),
    CONSTRAINT p_no_in_stage_nn CHECK (project_no IS NOT NULL)
    );



    CREATE TABLE expense
    (
        expense_id      NUMBER(4),
        description     VARCHAR2(50),
        quantity        NUMBER(2),
        unit_cost       NUMBER(5,2),
        chargeable      CHAR(1),
        project_no      NUMBER(4),
        invoice_no      NUMBER(4),

    CONSTRAINT expense_pk PRIMARY KEY (expense_id),
    CONSTRAINT expense_project_fk   FOREIGN KEY (project_no)
                                    REFERENCES project (project_no),
    CONSTRAINT expense_invoice_fk   FOREIGN KEY (invoice_no)
                                    REFERENCES invoice (invoice_no),
    CONSTRAINT expense_proj_no_nn   CHECK (project_no IS NOT NULL)
    );
```

**and the populate script**

```
    -- data represents: expence_id, description, quantity, unit_cost, chargeable, project_no, invoice_no
    INSERT INTO expense VALUES (1, 'total expence for building system', 2, 400.00, 'Y', 1, 1);


    -- data represents: project_no, project_code,  description, mgr_no, client_no
    INSERT INTO project VALUES (1,'MISTEST', 'HR System Development',1, 1);
    INSERT INTO project VALUES (2,'ECOM_MS', 'E-commerce System',1, 2);

    -- data represents: stage_id, project_no, stage_no, description, 
    -- start_date, planned_duration, fees_basis, estimate_date
    INSERT INTO stage VALUES (1, 1, 1,'Development of system',  TO_DATE('08-MAY-09','DD-MON-YY'), 40.0, 'VS', TO_DATE('17-JAN-09','DD-MON-YY'));
    INSERT INTO stage VALUES (2, 1, 2,'Testing of system',      TO_DATE('15-JUL-09','DD-MON-YY'), 40.0, 'VS', TO_DATE('17-JAN-09','DD-MON-YY'));
    INSERT INTO stage VALUES (3, 2, 1,'Rquirements Analysis',   TO_DATE('10-JAN-10','DD-MON-YY'), 40.0, 'VS', TO_DATE('17-JUL-10','DD-MON-YY'));
```

Comment: You gave us _way_ too much code, at least 100 lines or more.  Your error is likely being caused by trying to insert a record which points to a parent no longer in existence.  Please shrink down your question to something minimal.

Comment: ok i am just unsure as to where the problem lies and therefore what i can remove, so i shall make a condensed version above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to populate `expense` before `project`.

```
CREATE TABLE expense
    (
    ...

    CONSTRAINT expense_project_fk   FOREIGN KEY (project_no)
                                    REFERENCES project (project_no)
    ...
    );
```

The order of the tables in the DDL script would seem to serve you well for the DML script.

Comment: Upvote for just taking the time to sift through so much code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :-)

Comment: Just to clarify, move the insert  statement for expense to AFTER the insert for project. or set the order to the inverse order of the delete statements.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dudu Markovitz, you are correct the order in which i populate the tables was the issue, I placed expense after project and all is fine now. My sql teacher never covered that fact and i was unaware of that being a issue. Thank you for helping me every one especially Dudu Markovitz